# Beamer - Pause within inline math mode

Tags: beamer, math-mode, inline, pause

In the next MWE I created, there are 4 itemize texts associated with four components of an inline math mode equation. I would like that the math items are paused and appear exactly synchronously with the corresponding colored itemize texts. I know it is easy to be done when the math items are in different lines with `\only<4>{}` for instance. I could not find a way when all is inline.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Thème CambridgeUS
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg = darkred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg = darkred}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=darkred!90,
bg= blue!5}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=violet!90,
bg= darkred!5}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=blue!5,fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
% \setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=darkred}

\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
% \definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.2,0.8,0.2}
% \definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.52, 0.73, 0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\definecolor{dauphineblue}{rgb}{0.19,0.267,0.5176}
\definecolor{javerianablue}{rgb}{0,0.388,0.639}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.66,0.66,0.66}

\begin{document}


  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{RRSP - Objective function and parameter $F$, time duration of the failure}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
      \item[1.] \textcolor{darkred}{(a) MWE text 1}
      \item[1.] \textcolor{darkred}{(b) MWE text 2}
      \item[1.] \textcolor{teal}{(c) MWE text 3}
      \item[2.] \textcolor{darkgreen}{MWE text 4}
    \end{enumerate}

    \pause\vspace*{0.5cm}\centering$\displaystyle \text{Minimize}\mathbin{\textcolor{darkred}{\sum_{h\in V} o_hy_{hh}}} + \mathbin{\textcolor{darkred}{\sum_{hh'\in E}r_{hh'}x_{hh'}}} + \mathbin{\textcolor{teal {\sum_{(c,h)\in A}s_{ch}y_{ch}}}  + \mathbin{\textcolor{darkgreen}{B}}$

  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\uncover<>{}` wherever you want, in particular, inside the math formulas. An example based on your MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Thème CambridgeUS
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg = darkred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg = darkred}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=darkred!90,
bg= blue!5}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=violet!90,
bg= darkred!5}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=blue!5,fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
% \setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=darkred}

\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
% \definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.2,0.8,0.2}
% \definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.52, 0.73, 0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\definecolor{dauphineblue}{rgb}{0.19,0.267,0.5176}
\definecolor{javerianablue}{rgb}{0,0.388,0.639}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.66,0.66,0.66}

\begin{document}


  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{RRSP - Objective function and parameter $F$, time duration of the failure}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
      \item[1.] \textcolor{darkred}{(a) MWE text 1}
      \item[1.] \textcolor{darkred}{(b) MWE text 2}
      \item[1.] \textcolor{teal}{(c) MWE text 3}
      \item[2.] \textcolor{darkgreen}{MWE text 4}
    \end{enumerate}

    \[
      \uncover<1->{\text{Minimize } \textcolor{darkred}{\sum_{h\in V} o_hy_{hh}}}
      \uncover<2->{+\textcolor{darkred}{\sum_{hh'\in E}r_{hh'}x_{hh'}}}
      \uncover<3->{+\textcolor{teal}{\sum_{(c,h)\in A}s_{ch}y_{ch}}}
      \uncover<4->{+\textcolor{darkgreen}{B}}
    \]
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I didn't know this so suitable command! Many thanks :)